# Hiding admin nav bar in wordpress doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, wordpress

I used this for around a year to hide the admin nav bar

```
function remove_read_wpse_93843(){  
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'read' );    
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_read_wpse_93843' );
```

All of a sudden doesn't work anymore - every kind of user sees the admin nav.

How should I change the code?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://themeisle.com/blog/hide-wordpress-admin-bar/), all you have to do is add the below code into functions.php. They provide several other options as well.

```
/* Disable WordPress Admin Bar for all users */
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```